# Store pick up Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shipping-address

How can we show a checkbox at checkout if the customer wants to pick up their products at the store itself instead of getting it shipped to their address?

Can we do this without buying an extension for this?

Comment: https://www.mageants.com/store-pickup-extension-for-magento-2.html please check this, it might useful

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to buy any paid extension for store pickup. There are so many options you can try.

If you have only one store to pick up from, then you can try [this one](http://www.magepsycho.com/magento-2-custom-shipping.html) and set **`Store Pickup`** in the **Title** field.

If you have multiple store addresses, then you can try [this extension](https://github.com/mageclass/module-clickandcollect).

**Note:** I have not tried these extensions yet, so please do any exercise in the local repository first and be sure to backup your files and database before trying any extension.

Comment: Thanks for your recommend (y)

Comment: did anyone tried ? is this working. ? please let me know

Answer (score 3):

Now this is available out of the box starting from 2.4.0. Please check https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-in-store-delivery.html

Answer (score 2):

[These](https://files.classyllama.com/8127fd8e/20160112cvdmi.png)
are the only shipping methods available to use on a clean m2 installation.even Though the class does exists, we can't find any usages of \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Pickup so maybe magento hasn't implemented it as a carrier yet.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple if you do nut use free shipping use the free shipping part of magento 2.
Title "Store Pickup" and set the country's allowed to pickup at your store.
Minimum Order Amount to 0 or empty.

That is it

Answer (score 1):

By default, free shipping still forces you to enter an address - which could be confusing. Is there a way to prevent having to have that extra step for customers to fill in the address field (or choose a shipping cost even though it's $0)

Cheers,
Jeff